# It's possible to install socket.io manually?

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

i've installed nodejs on my work pc some weeks ago... today i've tried to install `socket.io` (via `npm install socket.io" on my stupid DOS terminal >_>`), but i've some proxy issue then i can't use npm...

It's possible to install `Socket.io` manually? Or i've to necessary use npm?

As always sry for my possibly bad english

P.S. my work pc S.O. is winXP

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes. It's possible to install a folder with npm without having to download it with npm. Just download the package source as a .tar or .zip file from GitHub here:
https://github.com/LearnBoost/socket.io

If you've chosen the .zip file, then unpack it and do a
`npm install <folder>`. With .tar files, you can install directly with `npm install <tarfile>`

Take a look here for further information:
http://npmjs.org/doc/install.html

Comment: i've to install all single package manually T_T but thanks for your clean answer!

Answer (score 5):

For Win7 64-bit, here's what I did to install Socket.IO:

1. Install node.js.  It ends up in "C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs."
2. Extract the socket.io zip file LearnBoost-socket.io-0.9.5-18-g3b9715e.zip into "C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\node_modules\npm\Socket.IO"
3. Open a DOS window (cmd) running as Administrator and change directory to "C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\node_modules\npm."
4. In that DOS window, run "npm install Socket.IO"
5. The new socket.io module is located in "C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\socket.io"

Comment: thakns, this is the only way I get a correct installation on windows 7 64bit

Answer (score -1):

Specific download link for the zip file: https://github.com/LearnBoost/socket.io/zipball/master

Answer (score -1):

surely restart the windows after install node.js and try this steps.Otherwise cmd say npm not recognize as internal or external command

Comment: Please expand your answer and make it more legible!